# Odoo : Create payment within the ODOO API ( v16 )

Tags: python, odoo

I am trying to get this working in python for odoo v16.

I am having an issue with addressing the correct model to register a payment.
I searched stackoverflow but nothing comes up for Python.

I tried with:

```
result_payment = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'account.payment.register', 'write', [[id], {'journal_id': 1, 'amount': str(400.0) , 'payment_date': '06/06/2023'}])
```

Anyone could point me in the right direction ?

Comment: Do you want to add an invoice payment?

Comment: yes. Tried Waleed solution but it doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `register payment` wizard record and pass the invoice model and ids throw the context then call `action_create_payments` function

***example:***

```py
inv_ids = [1]

wizard_id = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
    'account.payment.register', 
    'create',
    [{'journal_id': 1, 
      'amount': 400.0 , 
      'payment_date': '2023-06-06', 
      'payment_method_line_id': 1
    }], 
    {'context': {'active_model': 'account.move', 'active_ids': inv_ids}})

models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'account.payment.register', 'action_create_payments', [wizard_id])
```

Comment: im getting this now:

 <Fault 2: "You can't register a payment because there is nothing left to pay on the selected journal items.">

Comment: Odoo will keep lines having a [residual amount to pay](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/account/wizard/account_payment_register.py#L464). Try to check invoices before registering a payment

Comment: hmmm the invoices are posted but i can still click register payment in the frontend , i also dont find the field active_ids ? in the account.move

Comment: if i change it to active_ids
cache_value = field_cache[record._ids[0]]\nTypeError: unhashable type: \'dict\'\n'>

Comment: It is not a field name. The `active_ids` is a special variable used in the context, it holds the current records ids. Odoo will check if the invoice have a residual amount to pay, not if it is posted

Comment: Did you successfully create the payments?

Answer (score 0):

To create payment in Odoo 16 you will use `account.payment` model.

Example: Create customer payment:

```
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'account.payment', 'create', [{'partner_id':4089,'payment_type':'inbound','partner_type':'customer','journal_id':55,'payment_method_line_id':33, 'amount': 400, 'date': '2023-06-06'}])
```

To create vendor payment:

```
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'account.payment', 'create', [{'partner_id':5075,'partner_type':'supplier','payment_type':'outbound','journal_id':55,'payment_method_line_id':33, 'amount': 400, 'date': '2023-06-06'}])
```

Comment: But how would  you know this is for which invoice ?

Comment: You can use the code in @Kenly answer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the api, so you would do something like

```
   new_payments = [
    {
        'partner_id': 4089,
        'payment_type': 'inbound',
        'partner_type': 'customer',
        'journal_id': 55,
        'payment_method_line_id': 33,
        'amount': 400,
        'date': '2023-06-06'
    },
   
]

try:
    for payment in new_payments:
        models.execute_kw(
            db, 
            uid, 
            password, 
            'account.payment', 
            'create', 
            [payment]
        )
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

if you know the name or the id of the invoice, you could specify it like this.

```
    # Search for the invoice, you can use the name, but ID would be better. 
invoice_ids = models.execute_kw(
    db, uid, password,
    'account.move', 'search',
    [[('name', '=', 'Your Invoice Name')]]
)
if invoice_ids:
    invoice_id = invoice_ids[0]  # Assuming the invoice name is unique
else:
    print("Invoice not found")
    return

# Get the related payable/receivable account.move.line record
line_ids = models.execute_kw(
    db, uid, password,
    'account.move.line', 'search',
    [[('move_id', '=', invoice_id), ('account_id.user_type_id.type', 'in', ['receivable', 'payable'])]]
)
if line_ids:
    line_id = line_ids[0]  # Assuming there's only one payable/receivable line
else:
    print("Invoice line not found")
    return

# Create the payment
payment_id = models.execute_kw(
    db, uid, password,
    'account.payment', 'create',
    [{
        'partner_id': 4089,
        'payment_type': 'inbound',
        'partner_type': 'customer',
        'journal_id': 55,
        'payment_method_line_id': 33,
        'amount': 400,
        'date': '2023-06-06'
    }]
)

# Reconcile the payment with the invoice
models.execute_kw(
    db, uid, password,
    'account.payment', 'post',
    [payment_id]
)
models.execute_kw(
    db, uid, password,
    'account.move', 'action_invoice_paid',
    [invoice_id, 'done']
)
```

Comment: Tried this aswell:
type object \'account.payment\' has no attribute \'post\'\n'>